# QT UI double splitter

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I want to create a UI which will have two seperator (which user will use them to resize objects) and will look like below.

I saw some examples, but they was all creating UI widgets/components with code, I have to do it with UI designer, but I can't.

Anything I try just causes strange UI look.

P.S. Red lines supposed to be splitter
P.S.S. I'm using QT Creator (QT 5.2)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-Select `QTableWidget` and the `tabbed view`, click `Lay out vertically in splitter`

-and than select `QTreeWidget` and only the splitter created earlier (you can select those easier in the right panel - hold Ctrl click the splitter and the treewidget - make sure you select only the splitter not the widgets that are inside it) and click `Lay out horizontally in splitter`

-and finally select the main-window itself and click `Lay out vertically`.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm just curious what was wrong? Did you selected the widgets inside the first splitter?

Comment: I wasn't selecting "splitter", I was just selecting "Lay out vertically" :)